# idiomatic process synchronisation in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I am looking at how to code "map reduce" type scenarios directly in erlang.  As a toy example, imagine I want to decide which of several files is the biggest.  Those files might be anywhere on the internet, so getting each one might take some time; so I'd like to gather them in parallel.  Once I have them all, I can compare their sizes.

My assumed approach is as follows:

- A 'main' process to co-ordinate the work and determine which is biggest;
- A 'worker' process for each file, which fetches the file and returns the size to the main process.

Here's a clunky but functioning example (using local files only, but it shows the intent):

```
-module(cmp).
-export([cmp/2]).

cmp(Fname1, Fname2) ->
    Pid1 = fsize(Fname1),
    Pid2 = fsize(Fname2),
    {Size1, Size2} = collect(Pid1, Pid2),

    if 
        Size1 > Size2 ->
            io:format("The first file is bigger~n");
        Size2 > Size1 ->
            io:format("The second file is bigger~n");
        true ->
            io:format("The files are the same size~n")
    end.

 fsize(Fname) ->
    Pid = spawn(?MODULE, fsize, [self(), Fname]),
    Pid.

 fsize(Sender, Fname) ->
    Size = filelib:file_size(Fname),
    Sender ! {self(), Fname, Size}.

 collect(Pid1, Pid2) ->
    receive
        {Pida, Fnamea, Sizea} ->
            io:format("Pid: ~p, Fname: ~p, Size: ~p~n", [Pida, Fnamea, Sizea])
    end,
    receive
        {Pidb, Fnameb, Sizeb} ->
            io:format("Pid: ~p, Fname: ~p, Size: ~p~n", [Pidb, Fnameb, Sizeb])
    end,
    if
        Pida =:= Pid1 -> {Sizea, Sizeb};
        Pida =:= Pid2 -> {Sizeb, Sizea}
    end.
```

**Specific Questions**

1. Is the approach idiomatic?  i.e. hiving off each 'long running' task into a separate process, then collecting results back in a 'master'?
2. Is there a library to handle the synchronisation mechanics?  Specifically, the `collect` function in the example above?

Thanks.

--
Note: I know the `collect` function in particular is clunky; it could be generalised by e.g. storing the pids in a list, and looping until all had completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion it's best to learn from an example, so I had a look at how they do that in [`otp/rpc`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/OTP-18.3.3/lib/kernel/src/rpc.erl#L700) and based on that I implemented a bit shorter/simpler version of the [parallel eval call](https://github.com/yoonka/yolf/blob/master/src/yolf_p.erl#L35).

```
call(M, F, ArgL, Timeout) ->
    ReplyTo = self(),
    Keys = [spawn(fun() -> ReplyTo ! {self(), promise_reply, M:F(A)} end) || A <- ArgL],

    Yield = fun(Key) ->
                    receive
                        {Key, promise_reply, {error, _R} = E}           -> E;
                        {Key, promise_reply, {'EXIT', {error, _R} = E}} -> E;
                        {Key, promise_reply, {'EXIT', R}}               -> {error, R};
                        {Key, promise_reply, R}                         -> R
                    after Timeout                                       -> {error, timeout}
                    end
            end,
    [Yield(Key) || Key <- Keys].
```

Comment: thanks - a much more elegant implementation, and also validates the "many workers" idiom.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a [MapReduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) expert but I did had some experience using [this 3rd party mapreduce module](https://github.com/tvcutsem/erlang-mapreduce/blob/master/mapreduce.erl). So I will try to answer your question based on my current knowledge.

1. First, your input should be arranged as pairs of keys and values in order to properly use the mapreduce model. In general, your *master* process should first start workers processes (or nodes). Each worker receives a *map* function and a pair of *key* and *value*, lets name it `{K1,V1}`. It then executes the *map* function with the key and value and emits a new pair of *key* and *value* `{K2,V2}`. The *master* process collects the results and waits for all workers to finish their jobs. After all workers are done, the master starts the *reduce* part on the pairs `{K2,List[V2]}` that were emited by the workers. This part can be executed in parallel or not, it used to combine all the results into a single output. Note that the `List[V2]` is because there can be more then one value that was emited by the workers for a single `K2` key.

From the 3rd party module I mentioned above:

```
%% Input = [{K1, V1}]
%% Map(K1, V1, Emit) -> Emit a stream of {K2,V2} tuples
%% Reduce(K2, List[V2], Emit) -> Emit a stream of {K2,V2} tuples
%% Returns a Map[K2,List[V2]]
```

If we look into Erlangs' [lists](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html) functions, the *map* part is actually equal for doing `lists:map/2` and the reduce part is in some way similar to `lists:foldl/3` or `lists:foldr/3` and the combination between them are: `lists:mapfoldl/3`, `lists:mapfoldr/3`.

2. If you are using this pattern of mapreduce using sets of keys and values, there is no need for special synchronization if that is what you mean. You just need to wait for all workers to finish their job.

I suggest you to go over the 3rd party module I mentioned above. Take also a look at [this example](https://github.com/tvcutsem/erlang-mapreduce/blob/master/demo_frequency.erl). As you can see, the only things you need to define are the `Map` and `Reduce` functions.

Comment: thanks - I hadn't found the mapreduce module.  Not exactly what I'm looking for, but a good reference.

Comment: You can always make your own mapreduce module. For example, you can change the reduce part to be sequential and just use some kind of `foldl`. I used this 3rd party module for the [mutual friends mapreduce algorithm](http://stevekrenzel.com/finding-friends-with-mapreduce) for example.